# Can IMAP (Dovecot) be used to upload messages from a client to his mailbox on a server?

Tags: email, imap

Can an IMAP client create new and modify stored messages in his mailbox on remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, IMAP can be used to create new messages within a folder as well as to manipulate existing messages.

Comment: Manipulate as in move around, or edit message bodies too?

Comment: As in move around. Editing messages isn't part of the IMAP spec per se, although it can be simulated via deletion and creation.